# Laravel Horizon Jobs Stuck At Pending After Processing Few Jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I'm dispatching a lot of jobs (same class, same code) in a batch in Horizon queue.

After dispatching, some jobs process normally and the rest of the jobs gets stuck at "Pending".

```
[2022-04-05 19:11:55][c3d052b6-8664-4667-91ab-68040c9aaf6e] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:11:54][da8c78b5-1aae-4f6e-9d06-a3a28ea215fa] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:11:57][897a889a-7e59-4f06-871c-102952a8b5aa] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:00][92d83371-9edb-4dd8-bbf5-2700cc7e1212] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:03][d101eb54-1e92-44af-9b52-50a4a9592045] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:06][30513b4a-087d-4874-b8de-9eb5930e1224] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:09][274f8aa5-0990-46ed-b4c3-440036e5d0dc] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:12][603cd80b-d153-43a0-b1c4-122c5297e2fd] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:15][5d61e4d2-463d-4b4e-9863-8cc1ce19eaea] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:18][6996795c-e48f-4717-80a4-4056b21ccf1a] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:21][f28d802f-0ec8-4a1a-9e3b-cb2c425f05e7] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:24][72491e8f-f29b-417e-96f1-ee3af8171b39] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:27][ebdd54e7-e63e-4eb0-82cc-4dd748da4db6] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:12:30][d01bd49d-b850-4fdd-8ee4-01a3f3551833] Processing: App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:14:24][f28d802f-0ec8-4a1a-9e3b-cb2c425f05e7] Processed:  App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:14:23][ebdd54e7-e63e-4eb0-82cc-4dd748da4db6] Processed:  App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:14:29][72491e8f-f29b-417e-96f1-ee3af8171b39] Processed:  App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
[2022-04-05 19:14:31][d01bd49d-b850-4fdd-8ee4-01a3f3551833] Processed:  App\Jobs\Validation\DataValidationJob
```

[image] [image]

After processing the few processing jobs, the "current workload" goes to 0 jobs in all queue. And the pending jobs doesn't get picked up.

Comment: I would assume the processes crashes, but to check that find the processes in htop process list and see what happens when you process em

Comment: @mrhn any clue on what processes I should look for? I ran htop command and I see a lot of processes. Will I see failed processes if it crashes?

Comment: There will be all the horizon processes in there check before you spawn the jobs, when you then spawn the job see if they crash and respawn.

Comment: @mrhn will I see the "crashed" status? how do I know it crashed?

Comment: see if the process is still there or going away, you need to have some debugging mind for it, there is no easy way to debug a problem like this.

Comment: @XavierXames Do you solved this problem?

Comment: @VivekPawar no............